# How can I easily remove an information from a url?

Tags: python, django

my users will be redirected to my site with some information like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/dasbboard/?trxref=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f&reference=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f
```

using urllib will get give me

```
query='trxref=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f&reference=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f'
```

But I'm no okay with that, I want to be able to get the number after the reference(621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f), what is the best way to do it in my view? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first parse the url with `urlparse`, and then use [**`parse_qs`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse the querystring part:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/dasbboard/?trxref=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f&reference=621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
{'trxref': ['621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f'], 'reference': ['621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f']}
```

This is a dictionary that maps keys to a list of values, since a key can occur multiple times. We can then retrieve the reference with:

```
>>> data = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
>>> data['reference'][0]
'621538940cbc9865e63ec43857ed0f'
```